# How to add Items to a Listbox?

Tags: vb.net, scintilla, listbox-control

The line of code below adds each line too each index of the list Box.

```
ListBox1.Items.AddRange(CType(TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Item(0), RichTextBox).Lines)
```

This works however, if I wish to perform the same function as the line below but with the **ScintillaNet DLL**. I have tried the same thing with the use of the dll but it's not quite the same. Here was the code I tested:

```
ListBox1.Items.AddRange(CType(TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Item(0), ScintillaNet.Scintilla).Lines)
```

I am sorry I am asking such a silly question but I am a noob at the  **ScintillaNet DLL**.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What error do you get? Could you explain what it means _it's not quite the same_?

Comment: The error received is Error 1 Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'AddRange' can be called with these arguments:
    'Public Sub AddRange(items() As Object)': Value of type 'ScintillaNet.LinesCollection' cannot be converted to '1-dimensional array of Object'.
    'Public Sub AddRange(value As System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.ObjectCollection)': Value of type 'ScintillaNet.LinesCollection' cannot be converted to 'System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.ObjectCollection'.

Comment: @Steve by 'not quite the same' I mean that a richtextboxes code to get each line is slightly different to the code for the scintillar dll code. I am not sure how different and I am sure you can perform the function I wish to perform however I don not know the correct code for this to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `ListBox.Items.AddRange` method only accepts an array of `Object`.  The `ScintillaNet.Scintilla.Lines` property is a `ScintillaNet.LinesCollection` object, not an array.  As such, you cannot pass it to the `ListBox.Items.AddRange` method.

The `RichTextBox.Lines` property, on the other hand, *is* an array of `String`, so that can be passed to the `ListBox.Items.AddRange` method.

Unfortunately, there is no easy way to convert from a `ScintillaNet.LinesCollection` object to an array.  You could use it's `CopyTo` method to copy the collection to an array, but it's probably easier and more efficient to just loop through the collection and add each one individually, like this:

```
For Each i As Line In CType(TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Item(0), ScintillaNet.Scintilla).Lines
    ListBox1.Items.Add(i.Text)
Next
```

Notice that I am adding `i.Text` to the `ListBox` rather than just `i`.  As Steve astutely pointed out in the comments below, the `LineCollection` contains a list of `Line` objects.  The `ToString` method on the `Line` class simply outputs the line index rather than the text from that line.

Comment: I think that this tries to add an object of type `Line` to the ListBox. Probably it should be `i.Text`

Comment: ListBox.Items.AddRange() is substantially more efficient than ListBox.Items.Add(). As an example - a quick test to add 1,000 items:

ListBox1.Items.Add() completes in 2.5 seconds while
ListBox.Items.AddRange() completes in 20 miliseconds

Answer (score -1):

Building on Steven Doggart's answer, using AddRange() instead of Range() would look like this:

```
Dim lst As New List(Of String)

For Each i As Line In CType(TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Item(0), ScintillaNet.Scintilla).Lines
    lst.Add(i.Text)
Next

ListBox1.Items.AddRange(lst.ToArray)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
Dim ListA As New List(Of String)(New String() {"aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd"})
ComboBox1.Items.AddRange(ListA.ToArray)
```